# Scientific name of square root of negative number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, radicals

How do you call a number in the form:

$\sqrt{-4}$ ?

A non real number?

Comment: The mathematical term is usually "imaginary" or "complex", as in, "the complex number $0+2i$."

Comment: **The** square root of negative numbers is actually not commonly defined. -4 has two square roots, namely $-2i$ and $2i$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, why the downvotes..

Comment: @EricJohnson: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because a simple Google search would yield the usual terminology.

Comment: @BrianTung try googling it.

Comment: What is the "it" that you intended Brian Tung to google? I did [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=it), but I'm guessing you meant something else. (I didn't down vote either, by the way.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro +1 for highlighting my point

Comment: A Google search for "number of the form square root of minus four" yields some results and nice starting points

Comment: @EricJohnson: I think this is the kind of Google search people expect someone to do first: [square root of negative number](https://www.google.com/search?q=square+root+of+negative+number&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  Plenty of useful information there, which covers the ground provided by the answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$1)\,\,\text{complex,}$$ (all reals like $2$, $-\pi$ and $\sqrt5+1$ are complex) $$2)\,\,\text{non-real}$$ (which is, probably, what are you interested in) and $$3)\,\,\text{purely imaginary}$$ (which, you may say, is a coincidence: although all square roots of negative reals *are* purely imaginary, complex numbers include both real and purely imaginary numbers, *but* there are also infinitely many other complex numbers which are non-real and non-purely imaginary).

If this does not address your issue or you expect further clarification, please communicate via the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

In the 9th century, those expressions would have **no name**, because "they did not exist" (see the notice on [Mahavira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%ABra_(mathematician)#cite_note-FOOTNOTESelin20081268-12)).

**Imaginery number** once was a generic derogatory name for those ficticious or useless quantities. L. Euler used (in Elements of Algebra) also used **impossible numbers**.

Now those quantities are accepted, a negative number admits two square roots, here $2i$ and $-2i$, whose real part is null. They are often called **pure imaginary numbers**. As such, it is also a **complex number**.

But it is a solution of an algebraic equation ($x^2+4=0$), so it is also an **[algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number)**. And a **[Gauss integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)** as well, as it real and imaginary parts are integers. Yet, it is also a (model of) a **quaternion**, of an **octonion**, etc. There is a lot of interpretations of a quantity, and it really depends on you knnowledge and your goal.

A little [history of complex numbers](http://www.math.uri.edu/~merino/spring06/mth562/ShortHistoryComplexNumbers2006.pdf) could be an interesting reading.

Comment: Oh my! What happens when focusing on words, not numbers. Thx

Answer (score 0):

"Complex number" is frequently used. And sometimes they are called "imaginary numbers".

Comment: It may be worth pointing out the difference between complex and imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I call out " two ei!" when is pure imaginary.

For complex $ (2+ 3 i)  $  I call out " two plus three ei.. complex!"